# How to add multiple authors in same line

Tags: formatting, author

I am new to Latex so this might be really basic, but I wanted to add multiple authors for a term paper. This is my code for now.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}

\title{APA Project Proposal}
\author{Niharika Gupta}
\author{Saurav Kumar}
\date{15 September 2021}
\begin{document}


\maketitle

\section*{}


\section*{Abstract}
This 

\end{document}
```

However, when I run this, I get only Saurav Kumar as an author.

[image]

If I rewrite the author portion with an and, it pushes the author name to the next line and I want all the authors on the same line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}



\title{APA Project Proposal}
\author{Niharika Gupta\and Saurav Kumar}
\date{15 September 2021}
\begin{document}


\maketitle

\section*{}


\section*{Abstract}
This 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use `\and` inside the `\author` command. Such as: `\author{bla \and bla}`

Comment: In addition, to give a ref or extra note to one of the authors that are defined inside the `\author` command, you might want to use `\thanks`command. Such as: `\author{bla \thanks{thank you} \and bla \and bla}`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but as you are already using article class; instead of using `\section*{abstract}` you can use the environment named `abstract`. e.g. `\begin{abstract} This \end{abstract}`.

Comment: I switched it to this  \author{Niharika Gupta\and Saurav Kumar} but it just shifts the name to the next line

Comment: @TeestaaSaha Try removing the `authblk` package. It is changing the layout that you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked